# How to edit latency_timer without root privelege?

Tags: usb, root, usb-device

In my application, I need to edit `latency_timer` of a USB device to 1 since it causes large delay of communication.  Root privelege is necessary to edit it, but I would like to let normal users do it.

The `latency_timer` file is:

```
/sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer
```

which is 644/root:root.  Currently, I need to edit it after each boot with root privelege.

I think there would be two solutions, and both are acceptable to me:

1. Let normal users have a permission to edit `latency_timer`.
2. Change the system setting to set `latency_timer` always 1 when a device is plugged in.

How can I do 1 or 2?

(Note: the 'normal users' belong to the `dialout` group, and so they have regular read/write access to the device.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is using the approach 1.

First, make a bash script named `/sbin/fix_usb_latency.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
dev=ttyUSB0
if [ $# -ge 1 ];then
  dev=$1
fi
if [ -f /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/$dev/latency_timer ] && [ `cat /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/$dev/latency_timer` -gt 1 ];then
  echo "Fixing the latency issue of $dev..."
  echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/$dev/latency_timer
fi
```

Then, edit `/etc/sudoer` to let a user or a group execute `/sbin/fix_usb_latency.sh` without a root privelege.

```
$ sudo visudo
```

To give a user akihikoy the permission:

```
akihikoy ALL=PASSWD: ALL, NOPASSWD: /sbin/fix_usb_latency.sh
```

To give a group dialout the permission (`%` indicates a group):

```
%dialout ALL=PASSWD: ALL, NOPASSWD: /sbin/fix_usb_latency.sh
```

Then the execution of this script does not request a password.

```
$ sudo /sbin/fix_usb_latency.sh ttyUSB0
```